# Creating page content from a large JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I have a very large JSON object, which serves as a data source from which my page is created. Currently I am able to load the whole object, create DIVs from it and the display it. However when the JSON is very big it takes a lot of time and then suddenly the whole content is displayed. I would like to load each child separately, or display the loaded content after each node (appending).

The JSON has the following structure:

```
{
    id:"0",
    text:"",
    children:[{
        id:"0-0",
        text:"",
        children:[...]
    },
    {
        id:"",
        text:"0-1",
        children:[...]
    }]
}
```

When I load this object I call a function which creates the container based on the root node and then a recursive function which gets executed for every child.

```
function loadRoot(wholeJson){
    var rootDiv = '<div id="frag-' + wholeJson.id + '"></div>';
    return rootDiv;
}

function loadChildren(wholeJson){
    rootDiv = $('#frag-' + wholeJson.id);
    wholeJson.children.forEach(function(child){
        loadChild(child);
    });
}

function loadChild(node){
    var newDiv = // create the div here..
    node.children.forEach(function(child){
        loadChild(child);
    });
    newDiv += "</div>" //close it        
    return newDiv;
}
```

This works, but as I mentioned it loads the whole content at once. How can I achieve the displaying of every child after it's created and not only at the end of script execution, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The reason why this happens is that javascript first processes your function in the background, and when it is all done, it's changes will be made. I do not know if its the best way to go. But `setTimeout` with a anonymous function worked for me. Just set the waiting time really low.

Comment: by really low you mean 1ms? so each child gets created with setTimeout as a callback?